# Typing foreign characters without installing keyboard layouts

Tags: windows, gratis, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

Reported by a customer we had some issues with special characters that were outside the ISO-8859-1 code page.

Since I learned Chinese for three years, I could personally reproduce the issue by installing the Pinyin keyboard layout and just typing a few Chinese words. But finally, this may be disturbing, since you get the Windows language bar and pressing key combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (which are often used in software development) toggle between layouts.

Other solutions could be

- typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad numbers</kbd> (hard to remember + not that easy to type on Notebooks without a numeric block)
- copy/paste special characters (open Word or Internet first)

All those solutions do not seem perfect to me. I'm looking for a solution that

- has easier key combinations than <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad</kbd>
- needs no additional opening of a program like a symbol table
- does not add languages to the Windows language bar and does not conflict with programmer keys (ideally it's configurable)
- works on Windows
- is gratis, open source preferred

Comment: you can change the shortcut key for changing language and layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [WinCompose [GitHub]](https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose/releases) that fulfills my needs.

- has a configurable "compose" key which I'll refer to as <kbd>♥</kbd> in the following. I'm using <kbd>Pause</kbd> now.
- has a total of 2200 combinations and they are easier to remember than NumLock numbers, e.g. <kbd>♥</kbd><kbd><</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> for the Unicode arrow `←` or <kbd>♥</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> for the diaeresis e: `ë`
- has no impact on the language bar and on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> (at least as long as you don't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as the combine key)
- is open source and gratis
- works on Windows 7 x64 SP1 (and probably others)

Comment: Good choice – also my favorite whenever I have to work on Windoze: sequences are even compatible with what Linux supports out-of-the-box, so I don't have to rethink each combo :) For alternatives, see [my answer on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/a/623576/143340) (initially made before SR came to live, but updated a few times).